# How to reload tabledata when i move between tableviewcontrollers

Tags: iphone

My Requirement is such that....i can abl to get datas dynamically in viewwillAppear method...but i want to map this dynamic data in to tableview.whts happening is that in first time only cellForRowAtIndexPath is called....but for subsequent times it is not called....please tell me how to resolve above issue

Answer (score 0):

you need to call [self.tableView reloadData]

[UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW19)